# Git not letting me add my github password when asking for credentials

Tags: git, github

I've recently changed my github password. I have set up a repo on github and have initialised it on my system. I then added the files and committed  them to the master branch. When I go to push something from an R studio project using:

`git push -u origin master`

I get this message:

`error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory
Username for 'https://github.com':`

This is expected as I have recently changed my password. So I add in my username as requested. I then get this message:

`error: cannot run rpostback-askpass: No such file or directory
Password for 'https://sue-wallace@github.com':`

This is where it gets really odd. I can't type anything at all into the space where I'm supposed to type my password. I've tried it in the terminal for my mac, the shell in R studio and in the terminal in R studio. It all results in the same issue, I can't add the password.

Anyone got any ideas what the issue might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to switch the repository URL from https to `ssh`.
You need to generate ssh key, add it to your profile and then change the URL

Source: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/user/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

#### Generating ssh key

- Open Git Bash.
- Run `ssh-keygen` and follow the on-screen messages (or simply click <kbd>Enter</kbd> till it over)
- Copy the key file (the content of the public key) located in:

  ```
   ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

#### Add key to Github

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo, then click Settings.
  [image]
- In the user settings sidebar, click SSH and GPG keys.
  [image]
- Click New SSH key or Add SSH key.
  [image]
- Paste your key into the "Key" field.
  [image]
- Click Add SSH key.
  [image]
- **change the repository url to ssh**

  ```
  git remote set origin <ssh url>
  ```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.